# How to conditionally left join records in one table that fall between two date periods in another table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I currently have the following two tables:

Please note I am using SQLite.

The first table is called url_table - it has a unique ID, a start_time, an end_time and a reference.

I am aware that the column for start_time and end_time are `TEXT` and that in order for a solution to work i would need to convert the data to a **date format** but i am unsure how as of yet.

```
CREATE TABLE "url_table" (
    "ID"    TEXT,
    "start_time"    TEXT,
    "end_time"  TEXT, 
  "reference" TEXT
);

INSERT INTO "url_table" ("ID", "start_time", "end_time", "reference")
values("abcd","2019-10-10 17:00", "2019-10-10 17:10","boy");

INSERT INTO "url_table" ("ID", "start_time", "end_time", "reference")
values("efgh","2019-11-10 18:00", "2019-11-10 18:10","girl");
```

The second table is calling_table

This table contains the fields; ID unique, start_time which should be date but is TEXT and reference

```
CREATE TABLE "calling_table" (
    "c_ID"  TEXT,
    "start_time"    TEXT,
  "reference" TEXT
);

INSERT INTO "calling_table" ("c_ID", "start_time", "reference")
values("agfhfghd","2019-10-10 17:05","boy");

INSERT INTO "calling_table" ("c_ID", "start_time", "reference")
values("fghfghfghrty","2019-11-10 18:05","girl");
```

My question is the following:

I would like to left join the calling_table to the url_table by the common column "reference" - but I would like to left join in such a way that I am joining where the calling_table's start_time record is between the url_table's start_time and end_time.

So for example - the first and second record of calling_table both have a start_time that falls within the first two records of the url_table - so this information will be joined to the url_table.

I am unsure how to do this with a left join.

Any help appreciated

**I think that the start_time and end_time columns should be dates to perform this - however I do not know how to do this in SQLITE so have left them as TEXT**

[sql fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/7dd2f/1)

Expected result is the following:

```
ID    | start_time | end_time | reference | c_ID | call.start_time | call.reference 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abcd  2019-10-10 17:00 2019-10-10 17:00 "boy" "agfhfghd","2019-10-10 17:05","boy"
```

Comment: Can you share the expected result too please?

Comment: Yes have updated answer above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the logic you want is:

```
select . . .   -- list the columns you want here
from calling_table ct left join
     url_table ut
     on ct.reference = ut.reference and
        ct.start_time >= ut.start_time and
        ct.start_time < ut.end_time;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/7dd2f/6) is a SQL fiddle.